# Ubuntu 14.04 - need ssh access on Ethernet to execute the commands and wifi access to send data

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, ethernet, iwlwifi

Ubuntu system has two interfaces - ETh0 & wlan0 
ETh0 is conected to local test network through switch 
wifi is conected to Access point

Eth0 got ip 172.18.201.100
wlan0 got ip 172.18.202.87

Default routes added

```
172.18.201.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 eth0
172.18.202.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 wlan0
```

the issue is when ssh session is opened without wifi ..it is success 
through this ssh session , wifi -- wpa_supplicant is configured for wpa-psk
At this moment the actual ssh session is getting lost and you are loosing the remote access to device . ANy fix is great help ! I took the google help but it did not resolve the issue. If any one faced the same , share the info to fix this

Comment: so you can only connect when wlan0 is down? Are you on the 172.18.201.x network when you're trying to connect, or on the 172.18.202.x network?

Answer (score 0):

Got two solutions for this --

First one -- Add default route on Ethernet interface and with less metric . 
This may be over taken by Wireless metric when it gets ip dynamically and adds its own dynamic route.SO I do not think this is permanent solution at all times

Second one -- This will resolve the issue

Edit Connections -> Selct EThernet ->Edit - > Genral tab -> Select check box
1) automatically connect to this network when it is available
2) all users may connect to this network

Ethernet tab -> add ethernet mac & mtu - automatic
802.1x sec -> default
IPv4 settings -> Method - Manual & add Addresses - 172.18.201.100(eth ip) 255.255.255.0(netmask) 172.18.201.254 (gw) . Also select check box - Require IPv4 addressing for this connection to complete

==> Routes - selct check box - Use this connection only for resources on its network

IPV6 -> default or as you needed just same as IPV4 settings

--
Ram